# How to get the installation path of an installed program on Windows?

Tags: windows, registry, installation-path

I would like to get the installation path of a toolchain. Depending on the computer the toolchain can be installed in different locations (*i.e*. `C:\Analog Devices/...`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Analog Devices`, ...).

I don't want to hard-code every possible location on my `setenv` script.

Is there any solution to get that information from the Windows Registry?

One solution could be to grep some keywords from the content of this path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders
```

Another solution is understand what these long numbers mean:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer 
\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\ADEFB7880088952499512225EF2F50E2
```

Comment: Is this Key helpfull? `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"Name"\InstallLocation`

Comment: It is, but I still have to loop over all the entries `942C3EFB901D1B85C795125B2E507B514905A312` which is not very convenient